# R: reorder variable name in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

For variable names written in the form of "text+number" (e.g. Day1, Day2,...), is it possible to sort it when using ggplot?

```
library(ggplot2)

dogname = paste0('dog', 1:20)
dt = as.data.frame(cbind(dogname, seq(1,10.5,0.5)))
colnames(dt) = c('name', 'age')

ggplot(dt, aes(x=name, y=age))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

The code above generates the following graph, however, dog1 is followed by dog10 instead of dog2. Would it be possible to sort it from small to large numbers?

[image]

Comment: Since your variable is already in the order you want in the dataset, you can use `forcats::fct_inorder()` to set the levels of the factor in the order you want (you may need to install package **forcats**).  But I would say generally the answer to this kind of question is to manually set the order of the factor instead of using the default order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using just `tidyverse` packages. We can get the number out of the name with `str_extract`, since I imagine that you are given these names in some order rather than creating them from scratch in order. Then, we can use `fct_reorder` to order the name by sorting by the number *as a number*, rather than as a string. You can see that `dt$name` is now a factor with the levels in the right order.

```r
library(tidyverse)
dt <- tibble(
  name = str_c("dog", 1:20),
  age = seq(1,10.5,0.5)
) %>%
  mutate(
    order = str_extract(name, "\\d+") %>% as.integer,
    name = fct_reorder(name, order)
  )
dt$name
#>  [1] dog1  dog2  dog3  dog4  dog5  dog6  dog7  dog8  dog9  dog10 dog11
#> [12] dog12 dog13 dog14 dog15 dog16 dog17 dog18 dog19 dog20
#> 20 Levels: dog1 dog2 dog3 dog4 dog5 dog6 dog7 dog8 dog9 dog10 ... dog20

ggplot(dt, aes(x=name, y=age))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
#> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to
#> adjust the group aesthetic?
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `gtools` to order the values.

```
library(gtools)
library(tidyverse)

dt %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(as.character(dt$name), 
                       levels = mixedsort(as.character(dt$name)))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = age))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image: Plot]